# Swift: Calendar app - coloring more fields

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing an app with calendar with swift. I want to costumize to look like this:

The problem is here :

```
func calendarView(_ view: YMCalendarView, dateRangeForEventAtIndex index: Int, date: Date) ->  DateRange? {
    if calendar.isDateInToday(date)
        || calendar.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: calendar.endOfMonthForDate(date))
        || calendar.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: calendar.startOfMonthForDate(date))

    {


        return DateRange(start: date, end: calendar.endOfDayForDate(date))

    }
    return nil
}
```

The code above is ok to color the first day of month, last, and the current day but i want to color ex: from 12.09.2018 to 15.09.2018 how to do?
 Help me please if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your event model look like? I guess it has a start and an end date, right? Fetch the event object by index in `dateRangeForEventAtIndex`, then return `DateRange(start: event.startDate, end: event.endDate)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use UserDefault to save that date where you want to start and then compare to your current date or etc if match then set color green else nil